# ValueError Cannot query "customer1@gmail.com": Must be "Customer" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save the customer to the Order Model, but the customer is not being saved, it shows `customer1@gmail.com` must be Customer instance. And also I want to save the seller to the Order model. Because, A product is related to a seller. When I order something, and after the order is saved, I should be able to see from which seller I bought that product from. But here I am not able to save the seller.

`cart views.py`

```
def checkout(request):
    cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    order_obj = None
    if cart_created or cart_obj.products.count() == 0:
        return redirect('cart:cart')
    login_form = CustomerLoginForm()
    signin_form = CreateCustomerForm()
    address_form = AddressForm()
    billing_address_id = request.session.get("billing_address_id", None)
    shipping_address_id = request.session.get("shipping_address_id", None)
    billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
    address_qs = None
    if billing_profile is not None:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            address_qs = Address.objects.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile)
        order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj, request)
        if shipping_address_id:
            order_obj.shipping_address = Address.objects.get(id=shipping_address_id)
            del request.session["shipping_address_id"]
        if billing_address_id:
            order_obj.billing_address = Address.objects.get(id=billing_address_id)
            del request.session["billing_address_id"]

        if billing_address_id or shipping_address_id:
            order_obj.save()
    if request.method == "POST":
        is_done = order_obj.check_done()
        if is_done:
            order_obj.mark_paid()
            request.session['cart_items'] = ""
            del request.session['cart_id']
            return redirect("cart:success")

    context = {
        'object':order_obj,
        'billing_profile':billing_profile,
        'login_form':login_form,
        'signin_form': signin_form,
        'address_form':address_form,
        'address_qs': address_qs,
    }
    return render(request, 'cart/checkout.html', context)
```

`order models.py`

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj, request):
        created = False
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user, active=True, status='created')
        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
            # if request.user.is_authenticated and obj.customer is None:
            #     obj.customer = request.user
            #     obj.save()
        else:
            obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user, cart=cart_obj)
            # obj = self.model.objects.new(customer=request.user)
            created = True
        return obj, created

    # def new(self, customer=None):
    #     user_obj = None
    #     if customer is not None:
    #         if customer.is_authenticated:
    #             user_obj = customer
    #     return self.model.objects.create(customer=user_obj)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)

    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="shipping_address", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="billing_address", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    shipping_total = models.DecimalField(default=5.99, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2) 
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='created', choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,blank=True, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = OrderManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

`billing models.py`

```
class BillingProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        created=False
        obj = None
        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj, created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(customer=user, email=user.email)
        else:
            pass
        return obj, created

class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = BillingProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

def user_created_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.email:
        BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(customer=instance, email=instance.email)

post_save.connect(user_created_receiver, sender=User)
```

`product models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description         = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    categories          = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=CATEGORIES)
    volume              = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10, default=0.00)
    volume_type         = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PRODUCT_VOL_TYPE)
    product_stock       = models.IntegerField(default=0.00)
    price               = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10, default=0.00)
    image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug                = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = ProductManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`Errors` in `cart views.py`
Errors are denoted with *****

```
billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
    address_qs = None
    if billing_profile is not None:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            address_qs = Address.objects.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile)
        ***order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj, request)****
```

`Errors` in `order models.py`

Errors are denoted with *****

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj, request):
        created = False
        ******qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user, active=True, status='created')******
        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
            # if request.user.is_authenticated and obj.customer is None:
            #     obj.customer = request.user
            #     obj.save()
        else:
            ****obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user, cart=cart_obj)*****
            # obj = self.model.objects.new(customer=request.user)
            created = True
        return obj, created
```

`accounts models.py`

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager() ## This is the new line in the User model. ##


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image/', default='profile1.png', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image/', default='profile1.png', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

`E R R O R`

Internal Server Error: /cart/checkout/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in 
inner
    response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\src\cart\views.py", line 70, in checkout

```
order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj, request)
```

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\src\orders\models.py", line 24, in new_or_get

```
qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user, active=True, status='created')
```

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter 
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1284, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1122, in check_related_objects
    self.check_query_object_type(value, opts, field)

File "C:\Users\debop\OneDrive\Desktop\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1103, in check_query_object_type
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Cannot query "duke@gmail.com": Must be "Customer" instance.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @KlausD. I have added it.. And marked it with *. These lines are giving the errors.

Comment: @IainShelvington I have marked the lines with *. These lines are giving the errors.

Comment: @DebopriyoDas is `request.user` a `Customer` instance?

Comment: @IainShelvington I created a customer user model. The `Customer` is a `User`. So, I thought if the logged in user can be set to the customer. But it didn't work. I am not bale to save the logged in user to customer. I am not sure how to get the customer

Comment: Don't mark lines in the code, add the error traceback as printed on your console.

Comment: Can you share the `Customer` model?

Comment: @KlausD. Okay. Wait a minute.

Comment: @IainShelvington yeah! One minute

Comment: @KlausD. Done. Added the traceback.

Comment: @IainShelvington Added the whole accounts model. Since I want to save both the customer and the seller to the order model. Please help.

Comment: @IainShelvington 
I tried this answer, then I got an error for AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'request'. So what I did was changed th request to customer. And in the views I defined a new variable customer and saved the request.user.customer to that variable and passed it to the order object and it worked

Comment: @IainShelvington. So now I can save the customer now. Would you mind helping me out with the seller part. The seller is not saving also. Since the logged in `User` is a not `Seller`. So I am having some issue, I am not able to understand that how should I get the `Seller` and save it to the `Order`

Comment: @DebopriyoDas you should be able to get the `Seller` using the same method since `Seller` has a `OneToOneField` to `User` - `request.user.seller`

Comment: @IainShelvington Okay let me try

Comment: @IainShelvington It didn't work. Since I am logged in as `Customer` it shows the `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /cart/checkout/
User has no seller.`

Comment: @IainShelvington A `Seller` Uploaded a `Product`. A `Customer` purchased the `Product`. Now after the `Customer purchased the `Product` the seller should be notified about it. But the issues here I am getting is. Since the `Seller` is not being saved to the `Order` the `Seller` doesn't get see what `Orders` the `Seller` has.

Comment: @DebopriyoDas might be better to ask this in a separate question. You'll probably need to include the `Cart` model too

Comment: @IainShelvington Please do look into it.

Comment: @IainShelvington  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61038761/12074240?stw=2 Please do look into it.

Comment: @KlausD.   https://stackoverflow.com/q/61038761/12074240?stw=2   Please do look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OrderManager` you need to user `request.user.customer` for the `customer` field, not just the user

```
def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj, request):
    created = False
    qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user.customer, active=True, status='created')
    if qs.count() == 1:
        obj = qs.first()
    else:
        obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=request.user.customer, cart=cart_obj)
        created = True
    return obj, created
```

Since `Customer.user` is a `OneToOneField` you can access the customer from the user using `user.customer`

Comment: I tried this answer, then I got an error for `AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'request'`. So what I did was changed th request to customer. And in the views I defined a new variable `customer` and saved the `request.user.customer` to that variable and passed it to the order object and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In the `OrderManager` I changed the `request` to `customer` and in the `checkout view` I

added a new variable `customer` and set the `request.user.customer` to this variable and passed it to the `order object` and then it worked. Because, when I when I used `request` it gave error showing `AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'request'`

`order manager`

```
def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj, customer):
        created = False
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=customer, active=True, status='created')
        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=customer, cart=cart_obj)
            created = True
        return obj, created
```

`checkout view`

```
customer = request.user.customer
    if billing_profile is not None:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            address_qs = Address.objects.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile)
        order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj, customer)
```