# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no seller

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Here I am trying to save the `Seller` into the `Order` model after a `Customer` places a successful order. As the logged in `User` is a `Customer` so it shows `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no seller.` But I want to save the `Seller` after a `Customer` places an order, so that the `Seller` can be notified that the `Seller` has a new order.
But in the `Order Model` where `seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, here it doesn't save the seller.

'cart views.py`

```
def checkout(request):
    cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    order_obj = None
    if cart_created or cart_obj.products.count() == 0:
        return redirect('cart:cart')
    login_form = CustomerLoginForm()
    signin_form = CreateCustomerForm()
    address_form = AddressForm()
    billing_address_id = request.session.get("billing_address_id", None)
    shipping_address_id = request.session.get("shipping_address_id", None)
    billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
    address_qs = None
    customer = request.user.customer
    seller = request.user.seller
    if billing_profile is not None:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            address_qs = Address.objects.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile)
        order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj, customer, seller)
        if shipping_address_id:
            order_obj.shipping_address = Address.objects.get(id=shipping_address_id)
            del request.session["shipping_address_id"]
        if billing_address_id:
            order_obj.billing_address = Address.objects.get(id=billing_address_id)
            del request.session["billing_address_id"]

        if billing_address_id or shipping_address_id:
            order_obj.save()
    if request.method == "POST":
        is_done = order_obj.check_done()
        if is_done:
            order_obj.mark_paid()
            request.session['cart_items'] = ""
            del request.session['cart_id']
            return redirect("cart:success")

    context = {
        'object':order_obj,
        'billing_profile':billing_profile,
        'login_form':login_form,
        'signin_form': signin_form,
        'address_form':address_form,
        'address_qs': address_qs,
    }
    return render(request, 'cart/checkout.html', context)
```

`accounts models.py`

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager() ## This is the new line in the User model. ##


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image/', default='profile1.png', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image/', default='profile1.png', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

`cart models.py`

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    # creating a new cart or getting the current one
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False # the cart exists
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True # Ceated new
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    # Associating the user to the cart

    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)

    quantity    = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

`product models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description         = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    categories          = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=CATEGORIES)
    volume              = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10, default=0.00)
    volume_type         = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=PRODUCT_VOL_TYPE)
    product_stock       = models.IntegerField(default=0.00)
    price               = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10, default=0.00)
    image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug                = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = ProductManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`order models.py`

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj, customer, seller):
        created = False
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=customer, seller=seller, active=True, status='created')
        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=customer, seller=seller, cart=cart_obj)
            created = True
        return obj, created


class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)

    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="shipping_address", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="billing_address", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    shipping_total = models.DecimalField(default=5.99, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2) 
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='created', choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,blank=True, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = OrderManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

`Traceback`

Internal Server Error: /cart/checkout/

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

File "D:\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\mondayBS\src\cart\views.py", line 68, in checkout
    seller = request.user.seller

File "D:\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

File "D:\mondayBS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 420, in **get**
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
accounts.models.User.seller.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no seller.

`Probably this are the lines that are not working properly. May be!`

`cart views.py`

```
order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj, customer, seller)
```

`order models.py`

```
def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj, customer, seller):
        created = False
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(cart=cart_obj, billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=customer, seller=seller, active=True, status='created')
        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, customer=customer, seller=seller, cart=cart_obj)
            created = True
        return obj, created
```

Comment: Is seller available on the `Cart` model? What if an order has multiple products with different sellers?

Comment: @IainShelvington No, the `Cart` model don't have seller associated with it. A `Cart` has a ManyToMany realtion with the `Product`, so if there are multiple products with different `Sellers` the `Customer` can still see from which `Seller` they have bought.

Comment: @IainShelvington I got your point. Since the `Order` can have multiple `Product` from different `Seller` and I am just trying to save a single `Seller` to that particular `Order` it's bad way to do it. How should I proceed with this?    **I added the `Cart model`** .

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried man. But I just couldn't figure it out. If you save time can we connect through screen share or anything. Anything. I won't take too much off your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing the `Order.seller` foreign key. An `Order` can have many products and many sellers so you need to notify all of them when the order is placed. You can get the sellers for an order like this or similar depending on related_names for relationships

```
Seller.objects.filter(product__cart__order=order).distinct()
```

You can then loop over the sellers to notify each one

Comment: Okay! I get it. Let me try